# Error when deleting item from database in SpringBoot: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have two tables, item and user, userId is a foreign key in item table using @ManyToOne mapping. I need to delete an item just by pressing a button on a bootstrap front end but I get the error: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`jdbc`.`ms_item`, CONSTRAINT `FKli14y8viufmofrho0tdmgqawy` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `ms_users` (`id`)). I understand that I can't delete a row from a db which has reference to another entity so Im wondering how I can delete. Another thing to note is that update works fine!

Here is my code:

```
@Controller
public class ProductController {

@Autowired
private ItemRepository itemRepository;
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
private ItemServiceImp itemServiceImp;

@GetMapping("/listItems")
public String listing(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("item", new Item());
    model.addAttribute("pageTitle", "Sell Product");
    return "addItem";
}

@GetMapping("/products")
public String listItems(Model model, Principal principal) {
    User user = userRepository.findByEmail(principal.getName());
    List<Item> listItems = itemRepository.findByUser(user);
    model.addAttribute("listItems", listItems);
    return "productList";
}

@PostMapping("/products/save")
public String itemAdd(Item item, Principal principal, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    User user = userRepository.findByEmail(principal.getName());
    item.setUser(user);
    itemRepository.save(item);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Product Listed for sale");
    return "home_page";
}

@GetMapping("/products/update/{itemId}")
    public String updateItem(@PathVariable("itemId") Long itemId, Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    try {
        Item item = itemServiceImp.get(itemId);
        model.addAttribute("item", item);
        model.addAttribute("pageTitle", "Update Product");
        return "addItem";
    } catch (ItemNotFoundException e) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Product Updated");
        return "home_page";
    }

}

@GetMapping("/products/delete/{itemId}")
public String deleteItem(@PathVariable("itemId") Long itemId) {

    itemServiceImp.delete(itemId);
    return "redirect/productList";
}

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "msItem")
public class Item {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long itemId;
@Column(nullable = false, length = 45)
private String itemName;
@Column(nullable = false)
private int itemPrice;
@Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
private String itemDesc;
@Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
private String category;
@Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
private String image;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private User user;


@Service
public class ItemServiceImp{

@Autowired
private ItemRepository itemRepository;

public List<Item> listItems(User user) {
     return itemRepository.findByUser(user);
}

public Item get(Long itemId) throws ItemNotFoundException {
    Optional<Item> result = itemRepository.findById(itemId);

    if (result.isPresent()) {
        return result.get();
    }

    throw new ItemNotFoundException("No Item with id: " + itemId);
}

public void delete(Long itemId) {
    itemRepository.deleteById(itemId);
}
}
```

Comment: You are trying to delete a parent row without first removing all its children rows

Comment: You might consider adding a Delete Cascade to the schema, if that makes sense to your database design

Answer (score 0):

best practice is to have remove boolean in your document and make it true or false it cause to have soft delete instead of hard delete

Comment: Im not sure how that would work ? where and how would you integrate a boolean into deleting an item?

Comment: change your boolean to false and update your document after that you have it but in your selects you should filter documents with that property boolean with true then you actually delete that document but you have it as archived